# How to get explanation of summary output when the summary is associated with a particular function?

Tags: r

For example, if I want to know what the outputs mean from the **tree()** function, I could simply call `?tree` to get the document. However, when I want to understand the output of `summary(tree)`, I don't know what to do. Because the **summary()** can be used with results from many functions, if I just call `?summary`, it gives me a general document but doesn't give me the document associated with a particular function (say, tree()). If I want to understand every output of a `summary(tree)` result, how can I get the right document? Thanks!

Comment: You can check for `methods('summary')`

Comment: @akrun I just tried ```methods('summary')``` and see "[41] summary.tree*" from the result may be what I want. Then I called ```?summary.tree```, but the document is exactly the same as ```?tree``` document. I still could not see explanation for the ```summary(tree)``` output. Did I use it wrong? Please further guide.

Comment: it is a generic function with multiple methods.  If you want to find the source code of the function, use `getAnywhere('summary.tree')`

Comment: @akrun When I tried ```getAnywhere('summary.tree')```, the R result shows "no object named ‘summary.tree’ was found." By the way, is there any document that explains the output instead of looking at the source code directly? Thanks!

Comment: @Catherine Depending on the package author, that documentation might not exist. From looking at the source code for the tree package, you can confirm that the author has not written separate documentation for `summary.tree`, and has just sent queries about it to `tree`. https://github.com/cran/tree/blob/master/man/tree.Rd So reading the source code is the best you can do. If you get a "no object found" error, then maybe the package is not loaded.

Comment: @Catherine I would assume the `summary` documentation for each method doesn't give much information as these are all summarisation for specific objects.  There is documentation for `?tree` which you can look into.  If your question is about understanding the code for summary.tree, the you can check the source code with `getAnywhere` as I showed earlier